# UIImageViews in collectionview are not recycled properly

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionview with 4 UIImageviews inside. These are there for showing specific icons on the cells. Unfortunately when I have a cell that populates all 4 image views with images it works correctly. But when a cell should only display less than 4 items, it sometimes ( so not always ) shows additional icons. It seems to be from other (previous) cells. Like its not recycled properly.

Here is my code. I have an outlet that stores all imageviews inside.

```
@IBOutlet var savings: [UIImageView]!
```

Next I have a method inside my Cell Viewcontroller that populates according to the given array of icon names.

```
func setPropositions(propositions: [SupplierProposition])
{
    for (index, item) in propositions.enumerate() {
        if index < 4 {
            savings[index].image = nil
            savings[index].setNeedsDisplay()
            if let image = UIImage(named: item.iconName!) {
                savings[index].image = image
            } else {
                savings[index].image = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you see I tried everything to make sure the imageviews are empty before rendered, but it doesn't work. Anyone that know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: When debugging stuff like this it can be useful to hardcode some cells. For example the first cell is hard coded to have some images and the first reused cell is hard coded to have none at all. Then you can eliminate datasource errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Like its not recycled properly

No. It's like *you* are not recycling it properly. It is *your* job, in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, to *completely* configure this cell. This cell may have been used already, so it may already have image views in it that you placed there earlier; and if the cell for *this* index path is supposed to have fewer image views, it is *your* job to remove the ones you don't want.